# Why SQL Choose Hash join for an input with estimate row is 1

Tags: sql-execution-plan

I am trying to understand why a hash join is chosen in below plan.
Then, why the bigger result is chosen to be the BUILD input.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e947c.png)

I attached the plan here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H18NQQ8zp cause it exeeds the limit question length.

This hash join make it 30s slower than if I force it to nested loop.